# Javascript Equivalent to the following CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to access a span inside a div:

```
<div id="one">
    <span>Hello</span>
</div>

<div id="oe">
    <span>llo</span>
</div>
```

To access the span with `Hello` in CSS I would do this

```
#one>span{//CSS style}
```

What is the equivalent of this in javascript?

Comment: [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: You say you want to get the span with `Hello`, but use `#oe` which would select the span with `llo` in it. Which is accurate?

Answer (score 6):

You can select this node with

`document.querySelector('#one > span')`

and if you have multiple nodes you can use `querySelectorAll` like this:

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('#one > span');
for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
  var node = nodes[i];
  // do stuff with node here
}
```

Comment: you can use `document.querySelector('.className')` to select by class but in your example your nodes have an `id` so you would use `#one`, and then you want to access a `span` so you have to do a tag (not class) selector: `#one span`

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.classname')`

Comment: Not a problem for most, but remember to check your average users browser [compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector) first.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use [jQuery](https://jquery.com/):

```
$('#one > span').get(); // as an array of elements

$('#one > span').get(0); // the first element (in your case, the 'Hello')
```

Comment: not sure what's wrong with your answer - you have my upvote

Comment: Obviosly this will only get first child of element, not all of them.

Comment: Yes, but he wasn't specific about the fact that he wanted all spans as an array. I will clarify.

Comment: Loading a large library to simply access the DOM when `querySelector` does the trick is not the easiest way.

Comment: @Andy Have changed "easiest way" to "one way" so as not to offend.